# Python serial in a class readline not working

Tags: python, class

I want to read values by serial from an application with serial interface.

Folling code gives the expected result:

```python
# Example 1

import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM'+'1', baudrate='9600', bytesize=8, stopbits=1, parity='N', timeout=1)
 
ser.write(b"@INIT0174\r") #init communication
    
for i in range (3):
    ser.flushInput()
    ser.write(b"@FBKVR01BB\r") # Read values
    sleep(0.01)
    print(ser.readline().decode()[5:-6])

'''
Result:  
-0.258785367012024\
-0.262508511543274\
-0.266262173652649
'''
```

Following code is not working as desired.

```python
self.ser().readline().decode()  #creates not expected output
```

```python
import serial
from time import sleep

class serTest():
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port
        
    def ser(self):
        """
        Initalize serial object
        """
        s = serial.Serial(port='COM'+ self.port, baudrate='9600', 
            bytesize=8, stopbits=1, parity='N', timeout = 1)
        return (s)
    
    def init(self):
        """
        open serial connection and write something to it
        """
        
        print('init')
        self.ser().write(b"@INIT0174\r")
        
        print('flush')
        self.ser().flushInput()
        
        sleep(0.5)
        #read a line
        output = (self.ser().readline().decode())
        print(output)
    
    def term(self):
        """
        close serial connection
        """
        self.ser().write(b"@TERM0178\r")

    def get_value(self, cycles=3):
        """
        Get value from application
        """
        
        for i in range (cycles):
            # ask for the value
            self.ser().write(b"@FBKVR01BB\r\n")
            sleep(0.5)
            print(self.ser().readline()[5:-6].decode())

test = serTest('1')
test.init()
test.get_value()
test.term()

'''
Result: 
init
flush
four empty lines
'''
```

Monitored outgoing answers from application in both cases with same content.

Howto achieve same result from function and class?
Classes are pretty new for me. I appreciate any comment to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call self.ser() inside this `init(self)` function, it creates multiple class instance objects each time, as you create `serial.Serial()` each time.

Hope this could solve your issue.

```
def init(self):
    """
    open serial connection and write something to it
    """
    
    print('init')
    serial_obj = self.ser()
    serial_obj.write(b"@INIT0174\r")
    
    print('flush')
    serial_obj.flushInput()
    
    sleep(0.5)
    #read a line
    output = (serial_obj.readline().decode())
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to use the ser.object in other methods of this class. Is this a good way?

```
import serial
from time import sleep

class instance():
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port
        self.ser_obj  = serial.Serial(port='COM'+ self.port, baudrate='9600', 
            bytesize=8, stopbits=1, parity='N', timeout = 1)
        
    def init(self):
        """
        open serial connection
        """
        self.ser_obj.flushInput()
        self.ser_obj.write(b"@INIT0174\r")
        # other stuff
    
    def term(self):
        """
        close serial connection
        """
        self.ser_obj.write(b"@TERM0178\r")

    def get_value(self, cycles=3):
        """
        get value from application
        """
        for i in range (cycles):
            # ask for the value
            self.ser_obj.write(b"@FBKVR01BB\r\n")
            sleep(0.5)
            print(self.ser_obj.readline()[5:-6].decode())
```

Comment: Yes, can be used in this way. :-)